# How to execute Vim substitute command without effect the current searching pattern?

Tags: vim

I want to jump to the lines containing certain pattern and determine whether or not to apply :s command.

But after applying :s command, the '/' register was replaced by the pattern in the :s command,
and it wasn't very convenient to jump with original pattern.

So, does it have a comfortable way to achieve this task?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your use case?! You search for X, jump to a match and then substitute X or do you want to substitute a Y? You do know about confirming a substiture? `:s/<search>/<subst>/c`

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers  Thanks for your comment. I want search for X then substitute Y with Z.  I know the c flag. but :s/<search>/<subst>/c will still change the original pattern X.

Comment: Perhaps you can show some examples. A global command might do what you need without having to resort  to functions or obscure settings: pe. `g/X/s/Y/Z/gc`

Answer (score 5):

Vim (version 8+) provides the `:keeppatterns` command which prevents the search register from being altered by your command. Example:

```
:keeppatterns %s/foo/bar/g
```

For more help see `:h :keeppatterns`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that via vim-script. Something on these lines should help :

```
function! s:CustomSearch()
    let oldsearch = @/
    :%s/pattern/replace/flags
    let @/=oldsearch
endfunction
```

Comment: You can also use `:keeppatterns`. e.g. `:keeppatterns %s/foo/bar/g`. See `:h :keeppatterns`

Comment: @PeterRincker I feel like that should be an answer on its own.  That fits this situation perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Another method to delete the last search pattern is provided on Vim's manual (`:help histdel`) :

```
call histdel("search",-1)
let @/ = histget("search",-1)
```